# I want to hide my main window and then open new window(tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Could you help me? I'm trying to close my main window and then create a new window. I'm using withdraw() instead of destroy() since I'm planning to use that widget later.

Here is my code, but I just get:  `tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage10" doesn't exist`

I separated the codes of the main window and a new window into two python file, which are "Page1" and "Page2".

Sorry for my rough English.
Any help to fix this would be much appreciated:)

`tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage10" doesn't exist`seems to occur at `image_2 = canvas.create_image(`

Page1

```
    from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage

　　　OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
　　　ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path("./assets")



　　　def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
       return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)





　　　window = Tk()

　　　window.geometry("703x981")
　　　window.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")

     button_image_6 = PhotoImage(
         file=relative_to_assets("button_6.png"))
     button_6 = Button(
         image=button_image_6,
         borderwidth=0,
         highlightthickness=0,
         command=lambda: ("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", nextPage()),
         relief="flat"
     )
     button_6.place(
         x=415.0,
         y=793.0,
         width=86.0,
         height=78.0
     )

    
    def nextPage():
        window.withdraw()
        import Page2
```

Page2

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage
    
window = Tk()

def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)



window.geometry("545x470")
window.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")

window.title('PythonGuides')
canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#FFFFFF",
    height = 470,
    width = 545,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)

canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
image_image_2 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_2.png"))
image_2 = canvas.create_image(
    272.0,
    175.0,
    image=image_image_2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's happening because the image you are trying to add on the button is not present where you are trying to access it from.

And seems you have missed this:

1. You didn't pack the button
2. You didn't run the .mainloop() i.e window.mainloop()
3. and what does the :

   [enter the image description here][1]

is meant to do ?

I didn't use this and the code ran perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, I only included part of the code. 3 is my mistake. I will put it up again.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by having multiple instances of `Tk`. Having multiple instances of `Tk` can cause errors. Use `Toplevel` instead for additional windows.

Change `window = Tk()` to `window = Toplevel()` in `Page2`. You will also need to add `Toplevel` to your import list.